# Issue with the Public IP Address when Connected to the VPN Client

Tags: azure, azure-vpn

We have created an Azure VPN and configured it with the VPN Client before connecting to the VPN the public IP address which is there is similar to the IP address after connecting to the VPN.

Comment: Hi @Mohit, did the suggested solution work for you? Do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot or else do accept it for helping other community members.

Answer (score 0):

•   I would suggest you to please check the type of VPN connection that you have configured in your environment, i.e., P2S or S2S VPN connection. Because, in both the type of VPN connection, the VPN Gateway subnet, i.e, the client address pool defined in the VPN Gateway from which the connecting VPN clients pick up IP addresses for the connection has a public IP address or a FQDN published for the purpose of discovering the VPN Gateway and the inherent connection to be established to it.

•   Thus, each VPN gateway has a public IP published along with its configuration to which the VPN clients connect with the required configuration post which successful authentication takes place and the clients are assigned an IP address from the gateway subnet. Thus, the VPN clients have two IP addresses, one is the public IP address or the DHCP client address obtained from the internet connecting router and the second is the IP address from the VPN Gateway subnet.

•   Hence, after connecting to the VPN gateway subnet, only those resources are accessible which are allowed to be connected through the VPN Gateway subnet with the correct level of authentication approved for these resources.

For more information regarding the issues that you might be facing, kindly refer to the documentation link below for further steps and resolution: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-troubleshoot-vpn-point-to-site-connection-problems

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-troubleshoot-site-to-site-cannot-connect